# Launching Google Chrome 38 in background using node and socket-io

Tags: windows, google-chrome, sockets, windows-services, node.js

I need to launch google chrome in the background using service that will be using AD user.

Windows service is running node.js and i'm launching Chrome by request via Socket-io. Chrome should open selected page and once page is fully loaded, socket should close it.

The problem is that service opens Chrome and closes it right away and chrome is not even able to load requested page. Problem persists only if i run node in background using service.

Everything worked perfect before upgraded chrome from 37 to 38.

I also noticed that for each open instance of Chrome there is one instance of rundll32.exe (chrome is using it for flash). And rundll32.exe instances are persistent and looks like they are crashing chrome. i dont see any rundll32.exe when I run node and launch chrome in foreground.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I launched chrome with `--enable-logging --v=1` and i saw these errors. Not sure what to do with them though.

```
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(418)] Failed to establish GPU channel.
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:1872:1023/153655:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:3408:1023/153656:VERBOSE1:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(3477)] CT Verification complete: result -158 Invalid scts: 0 Verified scts: 0 scts from unknown logs: 0
[1844:3408:1023/153656:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(344)] Failed to launch child process
[1844:3408:1023/153701:VERBOSE1:bandwidth_metrics.h(95)] Bandwidth: 294975Kbps (avg 294975Kbps)
[1844:3408:1023/153723:VERBOSE1:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(3477)] CT Verification complete: result -158 Invalid scts: 0 Verified scts: 0 scts from unknown logs: 0
```

**UPDATE**

Opened issue with Chronium:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426858&thanks=426858&ts=1414158389

Comment: does chrome write anything on the windows logs?

Comment: @JohnKiller no windows logs. also nothing in chrome://chrashes

Comment: *Failed to establish GPU channel.* seems to be graphics related. Does Chrome has a "hardware acceleration" or "graphical acceleration" setting ? Disable them. Also disable third-party plugins, especially Flash (that uses graphics acceleration by default).

Comment: @AndréDaniel I dont see these errors anymore. Tried to disable flash plugin and (all plugins) including deleting PrepFlash dll from Chrome. Issue still persists

Comment: @rinchik the issue still persists but at least you fixed these errors, that's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem with slightly different setup. We have a TeamCity agent on a server, running protractor over node.js that opens Chrome in background with WebDriver. This stopped working a couple of days ago, and after some research we came to a similar log files as yours. I would assume, there's indeed a problem with Chrome 38 for running in background. When protractor is started from console all works properly.

**A solution** for us was to **downgrade Chrome to 37** and to disable automatic updates. It isn't so straightforward, since Google doesn't publish older versions. You may search for "Chrome 37 download" or see at one of other computers. Chrome preserves installers at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\37.0.2062.124\Installer`. Just pay attention is should be more than ~20MB for being offline and not online.

Comment: Looks like nobody else has an idea how to fix this issue without downgrading it :) Your answer was helpful though. Thank you :) I will accept it as the right one